# How do I make my labels and input boxes align with the next row?

Tags: html

I have the following codes that I want the next line of labels and input boxes to be align with the first row of input boxes. How can I achieve that?
I added the **class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"** for each row but it doesn't work.

```
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 20px auto; float:left">
    <form action="/view" method="POST" style="white-space: nowrap;">
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="1" class="control-label">Ingot Order</label>
            <input type="text" id="1" class="form-control">
            <label for="2" class="control-label">Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="2" name="number" class="form-control">         
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="3" class="control-label">Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="3" class="form-control">

            <label for="4" class="control-label">Total Pcs</label>
            <input type="text" id="4" class="form-control">
        </div>
```

**Update: It seems there's some confusion to the statement that I made. So I updated a picture to show what I want my display to be**
[The illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJQHh.png)

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then add label{width: 100px;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put each component into it's own `col` div. That way it keeps them the same width throughout.
[See this codepen](https://codepen.io/declanmcd/pen/ZrrJpy)

So instead of:

```
<label for="1" class="control-label">Ingot Order</label>
<input type="text" id="1" class="form-control">
```

You have:

```
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="1" class="control-label">Ingot Order</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" id="1" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap then your form element should have a class `container` for fixed width containers or `container-fluid` or flexible containers for `col-sm-6` class to work. See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/phartiyalpankaj/pen/KQQNbJ). Read [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) for more info.

Comment: I do have a container that's wrapping the form. Actually I need my second row which is the date and total pieces. However, the alignment does not align with the first row which is the order and number. I wish to have my input boxes to be the same on every row.

Comment: Please share a screen and Codepen / link if possible. Vertical alignment can always be solved by using flex if you don't want to support IE10 and lower versions. Read more here -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-7.